# Magento 2 _objectManager->create() method is not working for creating model object

Tags: php, magento

I recently created a module in Magento 2. Now I get the data from the database in front-end phtml file. The code is given below.

```
$question = $this->_objectManager->create('Magecomp\Firstmodule\Model\Firstmodule');
```

It did not work. Please help me to get the object of model.

Comment: have you found solution ?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this from a template. You should have a block that gets the data and provides a public method you can call from the template to get it